# browser_action to trigger content_script failed

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

What I want is when I click the browser_action icon, the webpage do some css, but it failed with the following code, it does not respond at all. Any idea?

The manifest json file look like this

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Test",
  "description": "yada yada",
  "version": "1.0",

  "permissions": [
    "https://*/*",
    "tabs"
  ],
    "icons": {
    "128" : "icon.png"
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png"
  },
      "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
            "http://*/*",
            "https://*/*"
            ],
      "js": ["jquery.js","request.js"],
      "run_at": "document_end"   
    }
  ]
}
```

and my request.js is here

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (){
  document.body.style.background = 'yellow';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you want to change the `css` of the relevant pages using [programmatic injection](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#pi). For that your *manifest.json* should include the following permission:

```
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab"
  ],
```

**Access to chrome.* API is restricted in content scripts**

> Once you have permissions set up, you can inject JavaScript into a page by calling tabs.executeScript. To inject CSS, use tabs.insertCSS.

So you would want to do something like this (injects javascript code):

```
 chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
   chrome.tabs.executeScript({
    code: 'document.body.style.backgroundColor="yellow"'
   });
 });
```

Alternatively, you could use the [insertCss](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-insertCSS) method as described in the docs on the activeTab like so:

```
 chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.insertCSS(tab.id, {
         code: 'document.body.style.backgroundColor="yellow"'
    });
 });
```

Again from the [docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts):

> If your content script's code should always be injected, register it in the extension manifest using the content_scripts field, as in the following example-

```
 "content_scripts": [
 {
  "matches": ["http://www.google.com/*"],
  "css": ["mystyles.css"], //mystyle.css gets injected into the relevant pages.
  "js": ["jquery.js", "myscript.js"]
 }
],
```

**EDIT** - I should have explicitly stated this earlier, but the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) clearly says that content scripts **cannot**

> Use chrome.* APIs, with the **exception** of:
>   extension ( getURL , inIncognitoContext , lastError , onRequest , sendRequest )

So you can't do something like the following in a *content script* (I wonder how it worked for you):

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function callback)
```

That said, you do have access to the `browserAction` API in the [background page(s)](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages). It would require something like this:

*manifest.json*:

```
 {
  ...
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },

 ...
 }
```

*background.js*:

```
 chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
   chrome.tabs.executeScript({
    code: 'document.body.style.backgroundColor="yellow"'
   });
 });
```

In essence use `chrome.browserAction` in background pages as content scripts don't support it. I hope I could clarify my point and this should help you get your problem sorted.

Comment: I follow ur code and I got this Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'onClicked' of undefined

Comment: If you could add the `onClicked` listener for the `BrowserAction` in your earlier code and you have the permissions set up correctly. I don't see why you get the error that you just mentioned. Just make sure you add the "activeTab" permission to your *manifest.json* file.

Comment: How are you modifying *request.js*? What's the code you are using?

Comment: chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
   chrome.tabs.executeScript({
    code: 'document.body.style.backgroundColor="yellow"'
   });
 });

Comment: @jsnoob, my bad I didn't clarify that `chrome.browserAction` can't be used in content scripts. I have updated the answer and the documentation clearly states it. It slipped past both our eyes.